# Android - AutoCompleteTextView onClick gives an error

Tags: java, android

**Solution**
If you want an onClickListener for your AutoCompleteTextView, do NOT do it in the XML, instead, do it in your Java File. See my answer below.

**Original Question**

Sorry if I'm missing out on something simple, but I've worked on this for the past 2 hours but I'm stuck.

In my activity, I have 4 AutoCompleteTextViews which are populated by an ArrayList, the values of which come from a database query. Everything works fine until I add an `android:onClick` property on any of the four AutoCompleteTextViews. I have no idea what's going on, cleaning the project did not save me.

Here are related code:

The global variables I used for the AutoCompleteTextViews:

```
private ArrayList<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> barcodes = new ArrayList<String>();

private AutoCompleteTextView brandACTV;
private AutoCompleteTextView itemACTV;
private AutoCompleteTextView partACTV;
private AutoCompleteTextView barcodeACTV;

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

My `onCreate()` function, pretty standard, I set my layout and initialize my AutoCompleteTextViews

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_page);

    TextView customerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customerName);
    customerName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("customer"));

    brandACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBrand);
    itemACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvItemName);
    partACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvPart);
    barcodeACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBarcode);


    new InitTask().execute("");
}
```

What happens in when I execute the `InitTask` thread is that I display a spinning progress bar while I do database queries to initialize my ArrayList arrays for my AutoCompleteTextViews.

In the InitTask's `doInBackground` method, I call my `getArrays()` function:

```
public void getArrays(){
            //itemListDB is an object of my DatabaseAdapter class
    itemListDB.open();

    brands = itemListDB.getAllBrands();
    items = itemListDB.getAllItemNames();
    parts = itemListDB.getAllParts();
    barcodes = itemListDB.getAllBarcodes();

    itemListDB.close();

}
```

And since I can't update the UI in the `doInBackground()` method, I call my `setAutoCompeteTextViews()` method in the `onPostExecute()` method of my thread:

```
public void setAutoCompeteTextViews(){

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brands);
    brandACTV.setAdapter(adapter);
    brandACTV.setThreshold(1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    itemACTV.setAdapter(adapter);
    itemACTV.setThreshold(1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parts);
    partACTV.setAdapter(adapter);
    partACTV.setThreshold(1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, barcodes);
    barcodeACTV.setAdapter(adapter);
    barcodeACTV.setThreshold(1);

}
```

For my XML, I'll only show how I wrote one AutoCompleteTextView since they're all similar, only the `id` vary.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/actvBrand"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/price"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/submit"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Brand"
    android:onClick="actvClicked" />
```

And I define my `actvClicked()` function in my activity as follows:

```
public void actvClicked(View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.actvBrand:
            Log.d("Hi", "Brand pressed");
            break;

        case R.id.actvItemName:
            Log.d("Hi", "Item name pressed");
            break;

        case R.id.actvPart:
            Log.d("Hi", "Part pressed");
            break;

        case R.id.actvBarcode:
            Log.d("Hi", "Barcode pressed");
            break;
    }
}
```

However, it does not work and logCat gives me this error:

```
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104): Process: com.agict.marswin, PID: 24104
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.agict.marswin/com.agict.marswin.SearchPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at com.agict.marswin.SearchPage.onCreate(SearchPage.java:39)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    ... 11 more
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    ... 24 more
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PassThroughClickListener.access$302(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1242)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(AutoCompleteTextView.java:200)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3797)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AutoCompleteTextView.java:137)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(AutoCompleteTextView.java:133)
04-25 15:40:28.270: E/AndroidRuntime(24104):    ... 27 more
```

And where `com.agict.marswin.SearchPage.onCreate(SearchPage.java:39)` points to my `setContentView()` call in my `onCreate()` function.

I'm sorry but I can't find any mistakes since I declared the function properly and there's nothing missing in my Java file that the XML would look for.

I'm confused and I don't know how to proceed. I would appreciate any guidance and help. Thank you.

Comment: 2 layouts with the same identifiers from different projects can cause this error.

Comment: if your data comes from sqlite db use SimpleCursorAdapter not ArrayAdapter

Comment: @user3294034 I closed my other projects and cleaned my project and nothing happened.

Comment: @pskink my `getAll****()` methods return `ArrayList<String>`. Would the problem really come from that if my code works perfectly before I added the `onClick` in my XML?

Comment: Related more recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363110/why-is-assigning-an-onclicklistener-to-autocompletetextview-giving-a-nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the onClick in the XML, I declared it in the Java File instead. In my `onCreate()`, I did this:

```
    brandACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBrand);
    itemACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvItemName);
    partACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvPart);
    barcodeACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actvBarcode);

    brandACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
    itemACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
    partACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
    barcodeACTV.setOnClickListener(actvClicked);
```

and I declared an OnClickListener function named actvClicked like so:

```
OnClickListener actvClicked = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.actvBrand:
                Log.d("Hi", "Brand pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.actvItemName:
                Log.d("Hi", "Item name pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.actvPart:
                Log.d("Hi", "Part pressed");
                break;

            case R.id.actvBarcode:
                Log.d("Hi", "Barcode pressed");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

However, my problem now is that I have to press on any of them twice before the onClickListener is triggered.